# How to reset a input tag field after taking one input to take another one

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to create a calculator using HTML and JavaScript. I have already written the code and it works. But the main problem is that I cannot reset the input tag after I have already taken one input(like a calculator). I have an input tag like this:

```
 Enter First Number:
            <input  id = "num1" placeholder = "First Number"/>
```

In my JavaScript there are functions like `sum()` which requires two numbers and functions like `sine()` which requires one number. So I want the input tag to be reset for taking another input after the first one for the `sum()` function. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you try `.val(''")`

Comment: Let me understand if I got you right, you want that third param for sum function will cause the input field to be reset?

Comment: Yes @Yossi I want the input field to be cleared so that I can give the second number as input for the addition

Comment: @The Viper's I think that I understand. So you have 1 input place, where multiple inputs can be, and you want that after each will inserted, your sum will take new input as param and clear this input field for next incoming input?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use jQuery? Can you give us a little overview of your code?
Its hard to give you an advice when we dont know the code.

In case of jQuery you can empty the inputs value by

```
$("input").val("") //Replace input with the fitting selector
```

Comment: No I am not using jQuery. Just some JS code in a `<script></script>` tag in an HTML file

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using jQuery you can use:
    document.getElementById('num1').value="";

This will clear the current value of the element. You should make sure that you have saved off the current value before you do this though.

Comment: I tried this. It's clearing the value alright but it's not giving me any time for the Second input. So when I give the first input and press the `+` operator it clears the field but immediately gives the result as `NaN`

Comment: I would need to see your actual code but it sounds like your sum method is being called before you input your second value. I would think that you want to call the sum method when you hit the equals button.